# How can I add an offset to the first layer to increase clearance?

Tags: g-code, adhesion, petg

My printer is calibrated for a certain clearance from the heated bed, which is chosen based on PLA.

I would like to try to increase it for the first layer for PETG, so that adhesion is reduced. The printer has M5 screws with 4000 steps/mm, so the resolution clearly allows that.

I don't want to modify the printer, I would like a G-Code or another option that I can apply in Prusa slicer in association with the specific filament when desired. I don't want to change the flow rate of the first layer, only the "zero" distance.

How can I do that?

Comment: In Cura it is easy, there is a Z offset option after you install a plug-in. To be honest, I print mostly PETG, but PLA with the same printer without making any offset changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Placeholders

I don't know if you are familiar with the [concept of placeholders](https://github.com/prusa3d/PrusaSlicer/wiki/Slic3r-placeholders-(a-copy-of-the-mauk.cc-page))? PrusSlicer is a derivative of Slic3r which uses this concept to insert [placeholders](https://github.com/prusa3d/PrusaSlicer/wiki/Slic3r-Prusa-Edition-Macro-Language) (sort of constants, with the possibility to do arithmetic) into your G-code (e.g. start or end codes) which are evaluated just before the slicer generates the final G-code upon slicing.

Unfortunately, although there is a constant for the filament type (`filament_type`), you cannot use a conditional expression as this does not work on string comparison (which should work with regular expressions...), but with some imagination you can fabricate a way to get past this problem.

E.g.

```
{if printer_notes=~/.*PRINTER_VENDOR_PRUSA3D.*/};Printer is Prusa{endif}
M117 [filament_type]
```

evaluates fine, but

`{if filament_type=~/.*PLA.*/};Filament type is PLA{endif}`

does not evaluate fine...

[image]

Solving this using placeholders, the printing temperatures for PLA and PETG are different, so in a conditional statement of the `first_layer_temperature` you could add an additional offset to the code at the end of the start G-code.

### Start G-code

A place to do this is the filament dependent start G-code section:

[image]

You can always edit this start G-code to include a manually set offset by moving the printer to a certainly height:

`G1 Z0.15`

and then redefining the zero level

`G92 Z0`

### Printer Z-offset

Note that a `z_offset` constant exists, so it is configurable in the graphical interface, if so, than I assume this fixes your problem instantly as the offset is directly applied in the final G-code. The `z-offset` option is part of the "printer settings" interface. This extra offset is added to the initial layer height movement.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your environment supports it, you can also use a G54 to add a constant offset to any positioning. So, you could use:

```
G53 ; clear offsets  
G54 Z0.15 ; add 0.15mm to every Z position
```

Just remember to clear the offsets at the end of your gcode:

```
G53 ; clear offsets
```