# Creality CR-10 problems with extrusion while printing

Tags: filament, extruder, extrusion, creality-cr-10, underextrusion

I have an extrusion problem with my creality CR 10 3D printer while printing.
I am using a standard 0.4 mm nozzle with a 1.75 mm diameter PLA and I use Cura as my slicer.

This printer worked perfectly fine and I stopped using it a few months ago right after the problem started.

When I try printing a `.gcode` file, the first layer is very thin but visible (it seems like the glass bed is engraved). However, after the first layer is complete, the extruder stops working properly. It moves forward then jumps backwards so it looks like the filament isn’t moving (I can also see the extruder’s marks on the filament). Also, the axis seem to move fine in all directions as I’m able to see a clear first layer.

However, when I go into the “prepare” menu of my printer and move the extruder, it works great as the filament flow is very smooth.

Hence, the problem is only visible while printing. I don’t think there’s a problem with the `.gcode` files as I printed them perfectly fine beforehand.

Comment: It looks like your nozzle is clogged. You need to perform a “cold plug“ (google it).

Comment: Please provide photos of the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Without images of the problem it is difficult to diagnose, but, the described symptoms sounds as if the nozzle is too close to the bed. If the nozzle is too close to the bed, and the extruder not strong enough, the filament flow is very limited due to pressure caused by a very small opening between the nozzle and the bed. Skipping of the extruder may wear out (grind) the filament and stop extrusion altogether.

Re-level the bed with a (thicker) piece of paper or with a feeler gauge. Alternatively, increase the height of the nozzle by re-defining the height or add an extra Z raise in the slicer (see question: "[How can I add an offset to the first layer to increase clearance?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/13330/how-can-i-add-an-offset-to-the-first-layer-to-increase-clearance/13334)").

Comment: "Re-level the bed with a (thicker) piece of paper or with a feeler gauge." The CR 10 has an automatic bed level system. When in doubt, run that program. The Z-adjustment is located near that option.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you're having an extrusion problem. Extrusion problems usually come either from a clogged nozzle (as @Adam S. said) or from the extruder it self. To determine where the problem is located I would first do a flow rate test using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWBkPIXTOlo&feature=emb_logo). When doing this test you can determine if the extruder is grinding the filament or if it's not grabbing it too much. After the calibration of the flowrate you can be certain that the printer is (by .gcode) pushing the correct amount of filament. If the problem persist I would first do an unclogging (since it's cheaper than the following option) using something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XR7tUVLku14).

If both previous options do not solve the problem, I would highly recommend you to by a mk-8 like metal extruder. After a while, the plastic one that comes with the printer loses force and you'll lose steps. Personally, I had a similar problem where the first layer was printed in a droplet pattern and was solved by changing the extruder to a metal one.

Try these options and if the problem persist you could upload some pictures of the first layer or a video. Other possibilities I think of are that the filament is having trouble passing through the Bowden tube or maybe you'll have to reasemble the hotend.